# Two level product collection sort

Tags: sorting, magento-2.1.4

Is it possible to sort the product collection in two levels, first sort the collection by position and if products have similar positions then sort by name.

```
|#|Product Name| position|
|2| bde        | 0       |
|1| bcd        | 1       |
|3| cde        | 3       |
|4| abc        | 3       |
```

The above is how the products appear on sorting by position but i want it to show as below:

```
|#|Product Name| position|
|2| bde        | 0       |
|1| bcd        | 1       |
|4| abc        | 3       |
|3| cde        | 3       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$collection->addOrder('position', \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
           ->addOrder('name', \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```